# Mac Terminal app - unable to use the up arrow to load previous commands when using SSH on remote server ( ^[[A )

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, ssh, remote-desktop

I'm running into a weird issue where the UP arrow no longer restores commands previously entered on a remote server during SSH session:

```
:~ user$ ssh user@myserver
//... type the password, get welcome message
$ ^[[A  //<- This is what I see when pressing up arrow on the server
$ ls //<- I expect to see my previous commands to be visible
```

**How can I make Terminal recall commands entered on a remote server when pressing the Up arrow?** This is the behavior that I've observed previously, currently running OSX 10.11.2

Comment: what shell is running on the server?

Comment: This is not related to the macOS terminal; this is a feature/issue with the shell of the system you are logging in to.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
echo $HISTSIZE
```

If that number is negative or zero, it will cause the behaviour you're seeing. You need to set it to a positive number in your remote ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc depending on the remote OS).

```
export HISTSIZE=100000
```

Comment: I had the same issue as OP, and my returned histsize was 500. I tried your solution anyway and it worked.

Comment: Just executing echo $HISTSIZE solved the problem. After executing this command console started work normally.

Answer (score 4):

Please try to temporarily change your shell, type the name of the shell:

```
$ /bin/csh
```

See if that fixes your arrow key. If so, your shell or shell profile is having the cause of the problem.

Possible solutions:

1. Fix your current shell or shell profile.
2. You can change to a different shell permanently.

Reference: [Mac OS X: How to change the Terminal shell](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005)

Comment: Thanks, I poked aroudn the settings and see that the terminal window has "SSH" in the window title, as opposed to csh or tcsh. Not sure how to fix that particular profile

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, using the C command `exit(0)` messes up my shell, causing this shell issue among others. Specifically this happened while I was fiddling with FFMPEG source code.

Hope this helps other confused googlers :)